# Error Message on my first App calculating 2 values learned from Youtube video

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, youtube

The youtube videos i have watched and learned are at links below :-

```
 Title is How to make an android app NO PROGRAMMING SKILLS NEEDED pt 1,2,3
 1.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be-YnLcPEdA , http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rt0wX3I1Wrg , http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkhRCWfTD4A.
```

I am a year 3 diploma student.i don't have any prior knowledge in programming and     app creation.I need to develop app for my final year project.Someone please help me.I  have downloaded android sdk bundle and tried to follow all as the youtube video done.

i have 3 error messages shown as below.:-

```
syntax error on token"(";expected.MainActivity.java .line28.type:java problem 
syntax error on token")";expected.MainActivity.java .line28.type:java problem 
Void is an invalid type for the variableCalculate.MainActivity.java.line28.type:java problem
```

Codes for main activity.java as below:-

```
     import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
     import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
     import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.MenuItem;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.TextView;
     import android.os.Build; 

     public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        } {
        public void Calculate( View v) {
            EditText num1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
            EditText num2text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2text);
            Integer num1=Integer.parseInt(num1text.getText().toString()) ,num2=Integer.parseInt(num2text.getText().toString());
            Integer ans=num1+num2;
            TextView answer =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answertxt);


            answer.setText("answer :"+ans.toString());
        }
    }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Codes for Fragment main.xml are as below:-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/num1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num1text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/num2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num2text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calc"
        android:onClick="Calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answertxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ans" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
codes for activity_main.xml as below:-
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

I need to learn how to make app because i needed to do for my project.In The real    project the smartphone Android KITKAT should able to use Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) from    RFduino and Receive data from advertisement feature in BLE from RFduino and send Data back to RFduino to do some task.My Email address is yokesmohan@gmail.com,s10135557@connect.np.edu.sg.Someone please help me.

Comment: In your `onCreate` method you seem to try to create an inner method called `Calculate`. You cannot create inner methods in Java. I'm not sure why you are creating that method there (you don't seem to be using it anywhere) so I'm not sure what the appropriate fix would be. But this is what is causing your compilation problems.

Comment: Its working after i move the calculate method outside oncreate method.thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    } {
```

In the line above, there is an extra open curly brace (`{`). Try removing it.